# In Google Sheets is it possible to print to a custom paper size?

Tags: google-sheets, printing

I have a spreadsheet that I'd like to print on a single 8.5" x 22" sheet of paper. This is not a standard paper size, but my printer can print on it.

The Google Sheets print settings dialog only shows me 11 paper sizes:

[image]

This isn't even as many paper sizes as show up in Chrome's print dialog. Is there a way to add other sizes to this list?

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible. According to [Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/143346?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), the page setup option is not available for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's not possible.  How smart do you think Google employees are?  Sure, they were able to guess how many golf balls would fit in an airplane during their interview questions, but supporting custom page sizes within a document is just way too mind-boggling.  I think Microsoft hired the only three people in the world who know how to do it.

Comment: What, it's not true?